# Kafka doesn't work with external NFS Volume

Tags: apache-kafka, snapshot, nfs, docker-volume

I am trying to run Kafka with mounted NFS Volume, facing exception and can not start Kafka:

```
    [2020-03-15 09:36:11,580] ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory /var/lib/kafka/data/.snapshot, '.snapshot' is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion).
Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2020-03-15 09:36:11,582] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory /var/lib/kafka/data/.snapshot, '.snapshot' is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion).
Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data.
        at kafka.log.Log$.exception$1(Log.scala:2150)
        at kafka.log.Log$.parseTopicPartitionName(Log.scala:2157)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.kafka$log$LogManager$$loadLog(LogManager.scala:260)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:345)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my docker-compose scripts:

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.2
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - zk-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data:nocopy
      - zk-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log:nocopy

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.2
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181 
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    volumes:
      - kf-data:/var/lib/kafka/data:nocopy


volumes:
  zk-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=18.0.3.227 #IP of NFS
      device: ":/opt/data/zk-data"
  zk-log:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=18.0.3.227
      device: ":/opt/data/zk-log"
  kf-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=18.0.3.227
      device: ":/opt/data/kf-data"
```

If I go to my NFS server,

```
ls -la /opt/data/kf-data/.snapshot

total 80
drwxrwxrwx 33 root   root         12288 Mar 28 00:10 .
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 21 19:20 ..
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 13 11:06 daily.2020-02-14_0010
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 13 11:06 daily.2020-02-15_0010
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 13 11:06 daily.2020-02-16_0010
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 13 11:06 daily.2020-02-17_0010
drwx------  2 root domain^users  4096 Feb 21 19:20 snapmirror.ka938443-8ea1-22e8-6608-00a067d1a20a_2148891236.2020-02-27_180700
```

There is a hidden folder named .snapshot, this folder is generated by NFS automatically and can not be removed. This is the reason why Kafka complains:  Found directory /var/lib/kafka/data/.snapshot, '.snapshot' is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion).

And this could be the general Kafka problem, is there any special configure or solution to let Kafka use the external NFS volume?

Any ideas will be grateful!

Comment: Have you tried creating a folder on NFS and using that as the Kafka data directory instead?

Comment: @Zsolt the data directory in NFS was always created manually. the directory .snapshot was generated every time by NFS when I create a new directory.

Comment: Looks like you can hide the snapshot directory from the NFS clients, but it is an NFS server side setting per volume, [here](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1034712/~/how-to-turn-off-access-to-.snapshot-directory-from-clients-) is a mention of this in the NetApp Knowledgebase, looks like the exact setting should depend on what kind of NFS server you are using.

Comment: This is highly discouraged way to run Kafka, btw. It prefers spinning disks, not network volumes

Comment: @Zsolt Thank you for the link, maybe I can try to turn off the access to snapshot. I will ask the other guys who are managing the NFS server.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I agree with you totally, that network volumes should not be used for Kafka. But......this is the decision of the management.

Comment: Does your management include Software Architects that have actually used/installed Kafka successfully before? Your brokers are running on machines with a local OS, right? What is stopping you from mounting physical, spinning, disks to those servers?

Comment: @cricket_007 because of some kind of security policies from management, we MUST persist all the "should be persisted' data such as MySQL database log, Kafka log in remote NFS server. I personally, had like to mount the local disk as volume. Sometimes we need to dance on the top of a bottle cap, without any choice.

Comment: Okay, fine. Then you need to use a NFS Vendor that doesn't create these snapshot directories. As answered, it isn't possible with your current solution unless you have a clean directory mount. Even in the blog you posted, it clearly states that topics and files cannot be removed without crashing Kafka (which basically means that you have an infinitely growing storage directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NetApp as NFS platform, this info could help: [disable 
 .snapshot access in NetApp](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1034712/~/how-to-turn-off-access-to-.snapshot-directory-from-clients-) is a global vFilter function, which is not a function per folder or share.

If you can not turn off the access to .snapshot, there is no solution, unless you use other NFS platforms, which will not generate .snapshot folder in every folder.

Answer (score 3):

As advised above Kafka on NFS is a flawed solution due to the way NFS file system works. You will run into issues with repartitioning and expansion. This is to do with the way NFS handles deletion of open files - silly rename behaviour. You can read about it in this blog post ([Kafka on NFS](https://sbg.technology/2018/07/10/kafka-nfs/)).

Comment: This is factually incorrect.  The issue is due to flaws in the kafka code where files are deleted before they are closed.  The cleanup code for removing files/directories in certain scenarios has race conditions in it which prevent kafka from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a hidden folder named .snapshot, this folder is generated by NFS automatically and can not be removed

Well, if there is no way around that, then Kafka will not be able to start, period.

---

To my knowledge, nowhere in the docs does it say remote attached storage is supported.

Comment: It is possible to use remote external Volume, of course, this is a bad way and not recommended. From this link, https://sbg.technology/2018/07/10/kafka-nfs/  They were using NFS volume before.

Comment: Okay, but what NFS Server software did they use? Clearly it didn't generate these snapshot files

Comment: finally I knew that we are using NetApp for NFS server. but the solution here [disable access in NetApp](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1034712/~/how-to-turn-off-access-to-.snapshot-directory-from-clients-) is a global vFilter function, which is not a funtion per folder or share. So this solution has been denied by our IT support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to not use the root of the volume? the .snapshot directory is only accessible on the root.

Comment: in our NFS, each directory has this .snapshot

Comment: You can mount the volume with NFS version 4, ONTAP will never show the .snapshot dir with NFSv4 - see the knowledge article -https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/Why_isn't_the_.snapshot_directory_visible_in_an_'ls_-al'_output_on_an_NFS_client%3F